# How to start a docker container for its contents only?

Tags: docker

I am building a docker container with only data (there is no service running). The data is mapped to the host.

What is the proper way to start a container from such an image?

My idea is to finish my `Dockerfile` with a

```
CMD /usr/bin/sleep 1000d
```

This will have no impact on the server and will be good for 3 years or so (which is plenty enough).

---

**UPDATE**: I was reluctant to give the whole context of why a docker container but since there are comments and by popular demand, here it goes :)

I self-host a myriad of services, all on docker. Some are pulled from Docker Hub (or similar) and some are my own code. They (= the ones I wrote) are deployed via a CI/CD served via a Caddy reverse proxy (all of them).

One of the services is a static site. I could copy the build artifact somewhere and have my Caddy serve it. It would work.

It would be very different from the other pipelines, though, and I would vastly prefer to be consistent because this is a home (amateur) environment and the more I streamline the production, the better.

Thus the idea of a docker container that runs a gimmick process (that does not grab resources) and that allows me to maintain a coherent CI/CD pipeline and final environment (with specific docker-compose and caddy configurations, per container in a neatly organized nest)

Comment: A container is a wrapper around a _process_; directly manipulating the data in a container is tricky, Docker-specific, and requires administrator privileges on the host.  Would another packaging mechanism be more appropriate?  (Why is this in a Docker container at all?)

Comment: Sooo, why start it? just `docker save`

Comment: @DavidMaze: I updated my question with some context.

Comment: @KamilCuk: I updated my question with some context.

Comment: I do not follow. The way you would do it is to package "Caddy" or whatever you want inside the docker container and have the docker container have _all_ the stuff that it needs to "serve it".

Comment: @KamilCuk: yes, that could be a solution as well (that I used in the past quite a lot, actually) but since I have a reverse proxy anyway, it could do the job of serving the static files.